# Working with namespace prefixes when a managed package can't be installed in sandbox

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, namespace

We have a managed package that connects our Salesforce org to an external application. Some fields from the managed package are writing information from Salesforce to the external app. So I want to write a trigger that modifies those fields. But I can't install the managed package in my sandbox and I can't create the fields in my sandbox since they have a namespace prefix. So any code I write just keeps throwing an error and not letting me save.

Is there any solution to this when you can't install the managed package in a sandbox?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new sandbox, or refresh your existing sandbox. The managed package will be copied as part of the create/refresh operation. It's imperative that you refresh your sandboxes frequently to make sure that you have access to all of the packages/licenses/features/etc in production.

Comment: And this will copy the managed package even if I can't create an outbound change set to my sandbox with the managed package components that I need?

Comment: @mplax Yes, a fresh sandbox is literally a copy of production metadata, including any installed managed packages. Try creating a Developer Sandbox to see how it looks.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it gave access when refreshing, but not with change sets. I couldn't refresh right now, so I had to create a new sandbox, but it works perfectly now and everything is available.